# Can Allure annotation be filtered while running on Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, allure

I have some Tests with Allure annotation (`@Story, @Epic`) and I'd like to run only those specific Epics on Jenkins job. Is there a way to parameterize it on a Jenkins job?

Answer (score 0):

The solution depends on test framework you are using. For example, for JUnit 5 you can use `PostDiscoveryFilter` to only select tests marked with Allure annotations (you can extract annotations from methods using `io.qameta.allure.util.AnnotationUtils`, complete example available [here](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-java/blob/master/allure-junit-platform/src/main/java/io/qameta/allure/junitplatform/AllurePostDiscoveryFilter.java)).

In order to pass selected epics to your filter the easiest way would be to use environment variables.

BTW, all that is implemented in [Allure TestOps](https://qameta.io)